# Multiple tabs/files in arduino?

Tags: arduino

I have looked so much but haven't find a good tutorial that cover all of this.
So, I need to break the project into multiple tabs/ino files, just to make it more clear.

So after you open a new tab, there are a few question I would like to ask:

1. If the main project file, lets say `main`, has another 2 tabs lets say `A` and `B`, so, every function in B would be visible to `main` and also `A`?
2. What happens with interrupts? If I have some interrupt that I define in file `A`, can it call the function of the interrupt in the `main` file?
3. What happens with `defines`? and `includes`?  if file `A` including some library lets say `Wire`, does the `main` file also see it and vice versa?

Whats the strategic to work with files? Do you add all your libraries to the main, or should you also add them to other files? (for example a file that deal with gyro and has to include some library)

Comment: The way #defines work is they just define some token in the Preprocessor. They don't have anything to do with extra files.

The way #includes work is they literally import the file into your code, as if you wrote it there instead of wrote the #include.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have always had trouble using the Arduino IDE for more than one source file. I would lean towards using something like [Arduino-Makefile](https://github.com/sudar/Arduino-Makefile) which gives you more control over the build process of your Arduino project.

1. You need to create a header file that declares these functions and then include that header file in you `.ino` file.
2. Assuming you are using the AVR library you can have the interrupt handler call a function (shown in Interrupt Handler). Then simply call the `interrupt_handler()` function outside of the ISR.
3. You should include the dependencies that are need for each file. That way if `A` or `B`removes `#include <Wire.h>`, your main file will still include the dependency. The file will not be included twice because of header include guards.

**Interrupt Handler**

```
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include "A.h"

/* Declare our ISR */
ISR(interrupt_vector)
{
    /* Call our handler (located in A) */
    interrupt_handler();
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much! i am not sure i got you. If lets say i need a file called A for some specific gyroscope operation. Do i need to create for it an .ino file and also an .h file with its functions and than include it to the main ? and regarding the ISR, can i listen to the interrupt call on A ?  Also , regarding the include Wire- the bottom line is that i need to put this include in A and B etc ?  sorry for having many question , i just couldn't make some order in your answer. thanks again .

Comment: If the gyroscope source file does not include your main() method I would put it in a .c file and not a .ino file. Then just declare the function in the .h file and write the implementation in the .c file. Then include the .h file in your main source file. I don't understand what you mean by "listen to the interrupt call on A". Include Wire.h in each source file that needs it. So if A and B use Wire include it in A and B. If A and main need wire include it in A and main, etc

Comment: ok thanks a lot. now i am bit confused about when to use c file and when .ino file, but thanks .

Answer (score 3):

You may have noticed that every .ino file must be contained inside a folder with the same name. Then, every other .ino file contained inside this folder is considered an "extra tab".

As far as I know, when you compile, the .ino files are merged as if they were one file. This is, for example, the cause of a startling "redefinition of void setup()" error, caused by having `setup` (or `loop`, or whatever else) in different .ino files in the same folder.

From "[the docs](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/BuildProcess)":

> ## Multi-file sketches
>
> A sketch can contain multiple files (tabs). To manage them, click on the right-facing arrow just above the scroll bar near the top of the environment. Tabs have one of four extensions: no extension, .c, .cpp, or .h (if you provide any other extension, the period will be converted to an underscore).
>
> When your sketch is compiled, **all tabs with no extension are concatenated together to form the "main sketch file"**. Tabs with .c or .cpp extensions are compiled separately. To use tabs with a .h extension, you need to #include it (using "double quotes" not ).

Although it mentions "files with no extension", I believe it applies to files with `.ino` extension as well.